# IOException in WPF GUI

Tags: c#, wpf, ioexception

I'm programing an app for Microsoft PixelSense, and I'm using WPF for developing the user interface.

The app needs to download some content from the internet. It should be able to cope with a situation when the internet connection suddendly breaks while downloading. So when I need an internet connection, I got a try catch and catch every WebException or IOException due to the internet break.

Here's a snippet of my code :

```
System.Drawing.Image tmpimg = null;
Stream stream = null;
HttpWebResponse httpWebReponse = null;   

try
{
    // dowloading image
    HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(urlPicturesBig +urlresource);
    httpWebReponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
    stream = httpWebReponse.GetResponseStream();
    tmpimg = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(stream);
    // saving
    tmpimg.Save(@appDirectory + "\\resources\\" + urlresource);                                        
} 

catch (WebException)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("WebException");                       
    return -1;
}

catch (IOException) 
{
    Debug.WriteLine("IOException");
    return -1;                   
}
```

The problem is that my GUI breaks down when the `IOException` is handled (a list of buttons becomes grey colored). So I've tried to do things this way :

```
try
{
    // dowloading image
    HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(urlPicturesBig +urlresource);
    httpWebReponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
}

catch (WebException)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("WebException");                       
    return -1;
}

stream = httpWebReponse.GetResponseStream();
tmpimg = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(stream);

// saving
tmpimg.Save(@appDirectory + "\\resources\\" + urlresource);
```

But even if there's an internet break, the `IOException` is handled, and the programm doesn't read `catch (WebException)` instructions.
If I remove try catch blocks, `WebException` is handled most of the time, sometimes it's the `IOException` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem as you state is that a failed network fetch can end up corrupting the backup resources you want to use.

As discussed in the comments below, this is due to the exception being thrown as the image stream is fetched from the network during the write to disk.  Using this kind of code should protect you against this. Needless to say, you should perform some sanity checking on the length of the stream that is being returned.

```
var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(urlPicturesBig + urlresource);
MemoryStream memory= new MemoryStream();
using (var httpWebReponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse())
{
     var stream = httpWebReponse.GetResponseStream();
     //read the entire stream into memory to ensure any network issues
     //are exposed
     stream.CopyTo(memory);
}
var tmpimg = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(memory);            {
tmpimg.Save(@appDirectory + "\\resources\\" + urlresource);
```

Comment: I don't see the point of copying in tempory folder. When a network issue occurs, I want to give up completely and don't try to copy to resource directory. But it doesn't work the way I did (return -1 before copying when a `WebException` is handled). Why ?

Comment: Possibly because you are obtaining a _stream_ from the network?  The error might occur at any time right up until the end of the stream.  I would have expected the Image.FromStream call to consume the entire stream (and thus generate all possible exceptions) before the files save though.  One other possibility would be that the WebException is happening on a deferred Dispose of the stream at the same time your file save is occurring.  Try wrapping the stream in a using block that closes before you do the file save.

Comment: Just read the docs for Image.FromStream which state "You must keep the stream open for the lifetime of the Image."  This implies to me that actually the exception is being thrown some way through your file save as the image tries to pull more bytes from the stream and the stream goes out to the network to fetch them.  You need to force the completion of the stream read before the file save in some way.  Dumping the image to a cache as I originally suggested is one way to do this but you could also try copying the image to another image or cache the network stream in memory before use.

Comment: Is `using` instruction a way to cache the network stream in memory before use ?

Comment: I've just updated the answer to show how you can use a memory stream to cache the network stream.  This is really only acceptable if you _know_ that the resources being returned are a sensible size.

Comment: Thanks, but I got an "NotSupportedException" on `var length = stream.Length;`, because stream is of type `System.Net.ConnectStream`

Comment: In that case, you can use the stream.copyto method.  I've updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Yes.  You will need to handle exceptions as normal.  This technique just ensures that the exception won't happen during the save to disk which was what was causing your original problem

Comment: If it's being thrown by the HTTP request, then your original image on disk should be unaffected.  If it's being thrown by the save operation itself then you have a different problem (possibly file contention) and need to adopt a different approach such as retrying the save in case it's just a transient condition.

Comment: I've successfully corrected the bug, in a very informal way, specific to my code. You've been very helpful, thank you !